# kill command doesn't work with redirection

Tags: bash, redirect, kill

ok so i am trying to execute kill command using

```
kill < ff // Doesn't work
cat ff | kill //Doesn't work
```

where the ff is text file containing a list of pid's.

```
7688 7697 7705 7760 7764 7772 7785 7810 7817 7865 7874 8036 8097
```

Output of kill is as follows for both the above commands is :

```
kill: usage:kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Comment: Try `cat ff > kill`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell builtin `kill` or the external one `/bin/kill` does not take Process ID (or Job ID) via standard input stream. You need to pass them as argument to `kill`, so:

```
kill -- $(<ff)
```

should do.

If you want to kill them one by one and doing something in between, you can create an array with the pids and iterate over them:

```
pids=( $(<file.txt) ) && for i in "${pids[@]}"; do echo "killing $i"; kill -- "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this?

```
kill $(cat ff)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

This one too:

```
$ cat ff|xargs kill
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using egrep (or `grep -E`) that accounts for some whitespace anomalies

`egrep -o "[0-9]+" ff | kill "$(cat -)"`

Which will work for a file that looks like this;

### ff:

```
7688 7697 7705 7760 7764 7772 

    7785    7810    7817 
    7865 
    7874

8036 8097
```

Comment: This example doesn't care about the current value of $IFS either

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Both of these works.

```
kill $(cat ff)
kill -- $(<ff)
```

It means that kill doesn't take inputs from standard inputs.